# Probability in Math Education

Tags: mathematics-education

Why is probability an under-emphasized subject in most math programs? Why does it seem that the hot topics these days are category theory and algebra? What do you think about the following: A student learns probability (both on the applied side and the pure side) and picks up the real analysis on the way. That way there is a purpose for learning the real analysis.

Can we do this with many mathematical subjects (e.g. first teach from an applied perspective, and learn the pure stuff because it is needed)?

Comment: My guess: Most people who are going to learn probability seriously will either specifically pursue it, or be in statistics. Not saying this is right, just that it works out.

Comment: Usually real analysis has a much larger role in a curriculum than supporting only probability.  Sometimes its integrated into the calculus stream.  It's a prerequisite for some algebra, geometry, topology, differential equations courses, and so on.  So if you put probability first, in effect you're delaying or minimizing the rest of the curriculum for a rather narrow "end".  I'm not saying it has to be that way but without more details from you it kind of looks like that. 

Comment: This is just my personal opinion, but I think learning pure mathematics just because it is necessary to do something applied detracts an awful lot from its beauty and elegance. I certainly would have avoided real analysis if I was told it was just some sort of advanced probability class.

Comment: I don't think this is a completely general observation. I know many places where probability theory is not at all under-emphasized at the undergraduate level. Maybe you're about graduate level probability?

Comment: In what parallel universe is category theory emphasized more than probability?

Comment: I don't think I know of a university with a regular category theory course.  Is there one?

Comment: Perhaps this thread would be more appropriate for meta?  It's asking a pretty subjective question and putting forward some contentious claims to motivate it. 

Comment: The question seems ambiguous to me: Undergraduate program or graduate program? I agree that every math major should have some exposure to probability and statistics, but that cannot be based on measure theory. At the graduate level breadth is usually enforced by requiring qualifying exams. Under the pick-and-choose model, there could be a qualifying exam in probability, which only a minority of graduate students would take. Under the older model, there would be qualifying exams in algebra, analysis and geometry/topology. It think it is unrealistic to *require* probability at the grad level.

Comment: @e -- an undergrad probability class _could_ be based on measure theory; it's just that there should be at least one other class which is not.  (BTW, a colleague of mine -- an algebraic geometer --  is preparing to teach an undergrad course on math. finance.  He showed me the book, which does introduce some measure theory, indeed in a quite nonchalant way: "Recall that a measure is..." I was very amused.)  Also, what you describe about the qualifying exams is the situation at UGA: students have an option of taking a probability exam, but most don't.  In fact it looks pretty hard to me...

Comment: @Everybody: I agree that probability is an excellent motivation for measure theory (and certainly that measure theory is an essential tool for serious probability).  In the last few years I have come to feel a little cheated that my early education in mathematics included a large dose of abstract measure theory (for what, really?) without making the link to probability.  Thus I think there is something interesting in this question...  

Comment: ...BUT I also agree that it is stated in a vague and contentious way: it's almost designed to instigate a pure v. applied argument.  I'm voting to close and at the same time stating my interest in seeing a retooled version of the question.

Comment: I broadly agree with Pete here. If there was a more concrete example (say, "look at the undergrad program at these universities, and look how little emphasis probability is given, why might that be") then that could be a fruitful question. As it stands, I'm not sure I even agree with the first sentence of the question.

Comment: I should also say that I know at least one university where the measure theory is held off until the 3rd year of undergrad studies, where it is explicitly taught as part of a course on rigorous probability theory. Worked quite well, I thought.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Wait... You know a university where measure theory is **held off** until the 3rd undergrad year?? At the school I just graduated from (undergrad), the real analysis course introducing measure theory is a second year graduate course... which admittedly seems to be unusual. 

Comment: Measure theory is a pretty standard 3rd or 4th year undergrad topic at most Canadian universities I know (Alberta, Calgary, UBC, Waterloo, Victoria, Toronto, ...)  While it'd be fine IMO to be part of a course with some emphasis on probability, I tend to see it more often on its own. 

Comment: @Mike: heh, my choice of "held off" was probably a silly one. Yes, we had some probability courses in 1st & 2nd year, but not fully rigorous (e.g. cts RVs treated by handwaving); and then the 3rd year had a fully fledged "probability and measure" course. But not measure theory in full non-$\sigma$-finite detail, for instance.

Comment: Of course, I never took measure theory, and don't seem to have suffered much for it.